# Express server not recieving Fetch POST request body

Tags: javascript, json, post, fetch, fetch-api

So I'm working on a react app and I set up a simple express API to add the details of a user into the database

```js
    app.post("/register", jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    console.log("body is ", req.body);
    let { username, firstname, lastname, password, role, className } = req.body;
    password = MD5(password);
    console.log(className);
    const query = `INSERT INTO users VALUES ('${username}', '${firstname}', '${lastname}', '${password}', '${role}', '${className}')`;
    conn.query(query, (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Registered Successfully");
    });
});
```

and I'm sending the POST request via the Fetch API

```
const response = fetch("http://localhost:8000/register", {
                                            method: "POST",
                                            mode: "no-cors",
                                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                                "username": username2,
                                                "firstname": firstname2,
                                                "lastname": lastname2,
                                                "password": password2,
                                                "role": "student",
                                                "className": "A1",
                                            }),
                                        })
                                            .then((response) => {
                                                console.log(response);
                                            })
                                            .catch((err) => {
                                                console.log(err);
                                            });
```

Upon firing the fetch request, I get the following on the terminal running the server

```
body is  {}
```

which causes the code further to error out

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you creating the query on the front end?

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/node-js-sql-injection-guide-examples-and-prevention/) yourself from.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what `jsonParser` is, but let's assume it is the return value of `express.json()`.

That middleware uses the `Content-Type` request header to determine if it should parse the request body or not.

Since you are passing `fetch` a **string** as the request body and are **not** explicitly setting a `Content-Type` header, it will be claiming it is sending `text/plain` data, so the JSON body parser will ignore it.

Note that you cannot set a `Content-Type` header to any value not supported by [`enctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype) without triggering a preflight, and that you cannot send a preflight in `mode: "no-cors"` (and you can't read the response in that mode either).

---

```js
const response = fetch("http://localhost:8000/register", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "username": username2,
        "firstname": firstname2,
        "lastname": lastname2,
        "password": password2,
        "role": "student",
        "className": "A1",
    })
})
```

Use the [cors middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors), on the server, to support the cross-origin request. Make sure you do it in a way that [supports preflighted requested](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight).

Comment: Thanks, this worked, also got to learn a lot :)